# Using Fontello fonts with Vite

Tags: laravel, vite, fontello

I've been using Fontello icons for a few years with webpack.  Now I want to use those same fonts on a new Laravel 10 site.  Laravel 10 comes with Vite, instead of the using mix along with webpack.

My problem is that when running npm run build I see the followig error for each of the fontello font files named (eot, woff, and svg):

./font/icons.eot?37060991 referenced in /var/dev/icons/resources/sass/app.scss didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime

And then the icons do not render in the page.

In the fontello/css/icons.css file the URL for each file starts with:

../font/icons.

I've tried various path combinations, like ../../fontello/font/, but nothing seems to work.

I would really like to continue using the Fontello icons, mostly because they make it easy to load only those icons images that we are actually using.  I can see that Vite is the way to go, at least for the foreseeable future, and especially when using Vue.  So gettng Fontello icons to work is pretty essential.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional searching around I found the solution:

I added an alias to the vite.config.js file:

```
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: [{
            // this alias it to allow us to include fontello icons
            find: '../font',
            replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/sass/fontello/font'),
        }],
    },
};
```

Be sure to add this line near the top:

```
import path from 'path';
```

Now 'npm run build' runs without warnings and the fontello provided icons appear on the page as expected.